# The sheet don´t get active

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The problem is that the sheet where I want to enter de value doesn´t get active so the value enter in the same sheet where it is

I think the problem is in the line 8, because with out them the sheet get active. But I don´t kwon why

```
function Pago(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 var row = ss.getRange('\'Entradas\'!B5').getRow();
 var ce =ss.getRange('\'Entradas\'!B3').getValue();
 var rowi = ce+row
 var code = ss.getRange('b5').getValue();
 ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Entradas'));
 sheet.getRange(rowi, 2).activate();
 ss.getActiveRange().setValue(code);
}
```

Comment: In your script, for example, when the active sheet is `Entradas`, when your script is run, the value of cell "B5" of `Entradas` sheet is put to the cell `rowi, 2` of `Entradas` sheet. On the other hand, when the active sheet is `Sheet1`, when your script is run, the value of cell "B5" of `Sheet1` is put to the cell `rowi, 2` of `Sheet1` sheet. For both situations, `rowi` is retrieved from `Entradas` sheet. In your goal, what you want to do? Can I ask you your detailed goal?

Comment: I have two sheets, one of them is `Sheet1` where I enter data. When the script run sort the data in the sheet `Entradas`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your showing script and `I have two sheets, one of them is Sheet1 where I enter data. When the script run sort the data in the sheet Entradas `, I cannot still understand what you want to do. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal? By this, I would like to try to understand your question.

Comment: The Cell `B5`  count the amount of data who is in `Entradas", of this way the script know where enter the data.(Below of the last one data)

Comment: @Tanaike
It is understood?

Comment: Don´t worry, I don't have a good english level either. What is your native lenguaje?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. For example, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? I thought that it might help understand your question. By the way, my mother language is Japanese. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: For Example my input is "C" in `Sheet1`, I need to sort the "C" in sheet `Entradas` but I Have a lot of other letters like "A" or "V" in the same column, so I need sort the "C" below the las one letter in the column.
Any way below they already gave me the solution I needed. Thanks so much for your help @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your replying, I couldn't still understand your question. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I think this is want you want

```
function Pago(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Entradas');
 var row = ss.getRange('\'Entradas\'!B5').getRow();
 var ce =ss.getRange('\'Entradas\'!B3').getValue();
 var rowi = ce+row;
 var code = sheet.getRange('b5').getValue();
 sh.getRange(rowi,2).setValue(code);
}
```

Comment: @Copper Thanks so much.


 It's too much trouble for you to explain me why my code don´t work how I expected.
Why this line of the code don´t active the sheet? `ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Entradas'));`

Comment: I tried looking at the code to answer your question and I'd guess that the problem is here `ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Entradas'));
 sheet.getRange(rowi, 2).activate();` When you change the active sheet to Entradas in the first line it changes what sheet means in the second line and in the same way it also changes what code is